# Ошибка сегментирования (сделан дамп памяти) семафоры

Tags: c++, linux, c

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/sem.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <string.h>

union semun{
    int val;
    struct semid_ds* buf;
    unsigned short *array;
    struct seminfo *__buf;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if(argc != 2) 
    {
        printf("no argument, for help %s -h\n", argv[0]);
        return -1;
    }
    if(strcmp(argv[1], "-h") == 0)
    {
        printf("To use, type in the file name as an argument\nExample: '%s file'\n",argv[0]);
        return -1;
    }
    FILE* file = fopen(argv[1], "w");
    if(file == NULL)
    {
        printf("Can't create file\n");
        return -1;
    }
    //открытие буфера
    if(close(open("./SHARED", O_RDWR, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR)))
    {
        printf("Can't open SHARED\n");
        return -1;
    }
    key_t buff_key = ftok("./SHARED", 1);
    int buff_id = shmget(buff_key, 1024, 0); 
    char* buff = (char *)shmat(buff_id, NULL, 0);
    //открыте семафоров
    //0 - свободно сегментов; 1 - занято сегментов
    //2 - защита; 3 - конец файла; 4 - для записи без остатка
    if(close(open("./SEM", O_RDWR, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR)))
    {
        printf("Can't open SEM\n");
        return -1;
    }
    key_t sem_key = ftok("./SEM", 1);
    int sem_id = semget(sem_key, 0, 0);
    semun init;
    count =5;
    printf("count = %d", count);
    //заготовки структур для semop()
    sembuf sem_wait = {0, -1, 0};
    sembuf sem_post = {0, 1, 0};
    //запись в файл
int last = 0;
    while(semctl(sem_id, 1, GETVAL) != 0 || semctl(sem_id, 3, GETVAL) != 0)
    {
        //дождемся наличия заполенных буферов и уменьшим на 1
        sem_wait.sem_num = 1;
        semop(sem_id, &sem_wait, 1);

        //защита
        sem_wait.sem_num = 2;
        semop(sem_id, &sem_wait, 1);

        //увеличим число пустых буферов на 1
        sem_post.sem_num = 0;
        semop(sem_id, &sem_post, 1);

        //запись нового блока в файл

        if(semctl(sem_id, 4, GETVAL) != 0 && semctl(sem_id, 3, GETVAL) == 0 && semctl(sem_id, 1, GETVAL) == 0)
        {
        }
        else if(semctl(sem_id, 4, GETVAL) != 0 && semctl(sem_id, 3, GETVAL) == 0 && semctl(sem_id, 1, GETVAL) == 1)
        {
            last = semctl(sem_id, 4, GETVAL);
            fwrite(buff, last, 1, file);
        }
        else
        {
            fwrite(buff, 128, 1, file);
        }
        //сдвиг буфера на влево
        memmove(buff, buff+128, 896); 

        //защита
        sem_post.sem_num = 2;
        semop(sem_id, &sem_post, 1);    
    }

    shmdt(buff);
    fclose(file);
}
```

От администратора запускается, так не хочет. Не могу понять где он лезет куда не надо..
Поменял всё на советы. Но проблема от этого не уйдет.
Вот думаю правильно ли с правами создаю. Создает эти файлы shared и sem другая программа вот таким способом:

```
open("./SHARED", O_CREAT | O_RDWR, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR)
```

Comment: Каковы владелец и права у файлов `SHARED` и `SEM`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ваша проблема состоит главным образом, в использовании уродливого подхода к обработке ошибок:

Вы пытаетесь заглянуть в хрустальный шар:

```
if(close(open("./SHARED", O_RDWR, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR)))
{
    printf("Can't open SHARED\n");
    return -1;
}
```

После чего, уже безо всякого контроля кодов возврата, делаете свое черное дело:

```
key_t buff_key = ftok("./SHARED", 1);
```

Избавьтесь от хрустального шара - анализируйте возвращаемое значение `ftok` и `errorno` согласно [документации](https://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?topic=ftok&category=3&russian=0)

Comment: Хмм. Не понимаю не много, ну я открываю shared на запись и на чтение.. Если нет, то уйдёт на ошибку. Или мне надо контролировать? Если пошло на -1 то тоже закрыть и уйти, а к чему тогда контролировать ftok и проверять его?

Comment: @Anrey - проверять надо обязательно ftok, а не гипотетическую возможность что-то там открыть. Никто не даст гарантии, что open работает полностью аналогично ftok на всех системах. 

Никто не даст гарантии, что файл не удалят между вызовами open и ftok.

Comment: @ изменил везде, теперь проверяю. Но это просто теперь контролируем ошибку. Но при запуске всё равно ошибка сегментирования. поправил свой вопрос снизу, посмотрите пожалуйста

Comment: @Anrey следующий шаг - сделайте отладочный вывод (со сбросом буфера stdout [fflush(stdout)] ) перед каждым системным вызовом - локализуйте ошибку.

Answer (score 2):

```
if(close(open("./SHARED", O_RDWR, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR)))
{
    printf("Can't open SHARED\n");
    return -1;
}
```

Старайтесь избегать подобных конструкций , такие конструкции часто приводят к непредсказуемым результатам, сложному поиску ошибок и читать трудно.

```
 int rc;
 rc = open("./SHARED", O_RDWR, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);
 if(rc == -1){
   printf("Can't open SHARED\n");
   return -1;
 }
```

Чуь больше кода, но можно явно локализовать ошибку.